# Windows 8.1 can't detect DirectX 9?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, uefi, directx, directx-9

i have really weird problem, just installed for couple times the Direct X 9.0c on my Windows 8.1 Update 1 64bit recently - but the system seems like doesn't assume if DX9 has installed, tried playing all my games that require DX9 runtimes to executing it, like GTA SA, PES 2013, FarCry 3, etc. but none of them can't even open, with some messages "need atleast DirectX version 9.0". i can find some DirectX stuff on Windows directory though (like d3d9, d3d8, d3dx9, etc. located on System32 & SysWOW64).

BTW, i've just reinstalled my laptop from Windows 7 where previously is Windows 8 preinstalled (UEFI) if that does matter.

Comment: updated. its my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Whoops my bad, recently i have been disabled PCA (Program Compatibility Assistant) service, which i think that was an "assistant-popup" while we're running application using compability mode, and not necessary. IDK if this service is really important for any programs compatibility. So i re-enabling it and voila.. Sorry wasting your time guys ):

Answer (score 0):

First check to see what's going on by trying:
Click Start, type CMD, press enter, type dxdiag, press enter.

This takes a minute but will show you a couple things: if directx is installed and what version you have. Being Windows 8 I believe it comes with directx 11 by default.

If that command isn't found for whatever reason I'd download the latest version from Microsoft, install, and see if that resolves the issue.

There may be another solution if that doesn't work (but I suspect this probably isn't the issue)- try running the games in compatibility mode.

Comment: DirectX 11 & DirectX 9 are different, although DX11 was the latest version, but if you haven't installed DX9, you can't play DX9 games which is the most all games nowadays using it. BTW its my mistake, but thx for trying help me, and sorry wasting your times and your eyes because reading my really bad english.